# How to write data to a subcollection of Firestore in v9 react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```js
db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection("messages").add({
  message: input,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
  user: 'Apollos',
  userImage: 'https://naniwallpaper.com/files/wallpapers/eren-yeager/1-EREN%20YEAGER-1080x1920.jpg'
});
```

How should this be in firestore v9?

Comment: I think the best way to check is the official docs. They even provide how to convert a V8 to v9 code

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const messageRef = doc(db, "rooms", chanelID, "messages");

const update = {
  message: input,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
  user: 'Apollos',
  userImage: 'https://naniwallpaper.com/files/wallpapers/eren-yeager/1-EREN%20YEAGER-1080x1920.jpg'
}

 setDoc(messageRef, update, { merge: true });
```